# Chrome extension inject remote JS file?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

Okay, i've searched for days, its time i give in and ask for help.

I've just begun trying to figure out Chrome extensions and am now in the beginning phases of development.
I dont know too much about it all, so im stuck on level one.

I need my background.html or a background.js file, or my content script. which ever is better suited for the job - to load an external script held on my server. http or https.

So i tried with the manifest file adding "matches" and security and permissions but to no avail.
I could show you my manifest file but i have ten thousand versions of it trying to figure out why it wont work.

i also tried adding it in the background.html file  - again errors of security and/or not able to load file.

So where i'm at: 
i have a manifest file version 2, 
i have a background.html - which loads in my content script
I have a content script which does a console.log so i know it works.

i just want my remote JS file to be loaded in :( and do anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar stuff, in the next code snippet is an example

manifest.json

```js
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],   
    "js": ["content_script.js"]
  }
],
```

In content_script.js you can load an external js file this way:

```js
//inject script
(function() {
  var myjs = document.createElement('script');
  myjs.type = 'text/javascript';
  myjs.async = true;
  myjs.src = 'http://mylocalhost/wrapper.js';
  document.body.appendChild(myjs);  
})();
```

Comment: To the down voter please tell me why was this downvoted.